# Generate Xml excluding the &gt; and &lt; using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, escaping

I have a requirement where in i need to remove the Root node and display the xslt on a webpage in XML format.

To make it more clear, I will directly give my desired output XML file and the Input XMl that I am giving.

My Input XML file is:

```
<cp:gtl xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cp="urn:schemas-microsoft-com/contentpublishing/content" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2005-03-30T18:40:19" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<cp:abstract>
&lt;weatherdata&gt;&lt;weather entityid="32226" alert="" timezone="5.5" long="72.8195343" lat="21.195015" attribution2="© Foreca" attribution="Data provided by Foreca" provider="Foreca" degreetype="F" imagerelativeurl="http://stjp.msn.com/as/wea3/i/en-us/" url="http://local.msn.com/worldweather.aspx?eid=32226&amp;q=Surat-IND" encodedlocationname="Surat%2c+IND" zipcode="" weatherlocationname="Surat, IND" weatherlocationcode="wc:INXX0157"&gt;&lt;current winddisplay="4 mph NE" windspeed="4" humidity="38" feelslike="90" observationpoint="Surat" observationtime="11:30:00" shortday="Wed" day="Wednesday" date="2011-11-09" skytext="Clear" skycode="32" temperature="90"/&gt;&lt;forecast shortday="Wed" day="Wednesday" date="2011-11-09" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="95" low="72"/&gt;&lt;forecast shortday="Thu" day="Thursday" date="2011-11-10" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="96" low="72"/&gt;&lt;forecast shortday="Fri" day="Friday" date="2011-11-11" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="96" low="72"/&gt;&lt;forecast shortday="Sat" day="Saturday" date="2011-11-12" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="95" low="75"/&gt;&lt;forecast shortday="Sun" day="Sunday" date="2011-11-13" precip="5" skytextday="Fair" skycodeday="34" high="96" low="79"/&gt;&lt;toolbar minversion="1.0.1965.0" timewindow="60"/&gt;&lt;/weather&gt;
&lt;/weatherdata&gt;
</cp:abstract>
</cp:gtl>
```

And my expected output file on Webpage is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<weatherdata>
<weather entityid="32226" alert="" timezone="5.5" long="72.8195343" lat="21.195015" attribution2="© Foreca" attribution="Data provided by Foreca" provider="Foreca" degreetype="F"   encodedlocationname="Surat%2c+IND" zipcode="" weatherlocationname="Surat, IND" weatherlocationcode="wc:INXX0157"><current winddisplay="4 mph NE" windspeed="4" humidity="38" feelslike="90" observationpoint="Surat" observationtime="11:30:00" shortday="Wed" day="Wednesday" date="2011-11-09" skytext="Clear" skycode="32" temperature="90"/><forecast shortday="Wed" day="Wednesday" date="2011-11-09" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="95" low="72"/><forecast shortday="Thu" day="Thursday" date="2011-11-10" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="96" low="72"/><forecast shortday="Fri" day="Friday" date="2011-11-11" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="96" low="72"/><forecast shortday="Sat" day="Saturday" date="2011-11-12" precip="5" skytextday="Clear" skycodeday="32" high="95" low="75"/><forecast shortday="Sun" day="Sunday" date="2011-11-13" precip="5" skytextday="Fair" skycodeday="34" high="96" low="79"/><toolbar minversion="1.0.1965.0" timewindow="60"/></weather>
</weatherdata>
```

However currently what is happening is I am able to remove the cp:abstract tag and my XML is visible correct on the web page, however when I View the page source, I still see < and > replaced by > and <

My current xslt which I have written is:

```
<xslt:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xslt cp gc"     xmlns:xslt="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:cp="urn:schemas-microsoft-com/contentpublishing/content" xmlns:gc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/msn/granite/cm"
             xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
<xslt:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>

<xslt:template match="gc:cm/gc:content/cp:root/cp:gtl">
    <xslt:apply-templates select="cp:abstract"/>
</xslt:template>

<xslt:template match="cp:abstract">
    <xslt:value-of select="." />
</xslt:template>
```

Can some one please help me correct my xslt so that I get the desired XML output?
Also note that XML under cp:abstract tag is random generated from feed. Sometimes it is fo weathaer, sometimes some other dynamic xml. All I want is root node under cp:abstract tag to be extracted on my webpage in XML format.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to escape your XML for display, regardless of the XML you have as input. That is, do you want to display some text that looks like your input XML on a web page?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct, for example i see this URL http://weather.in.msn.com/data.aspx?wealocations=wc:INXX0157.

The XML is visible on this page. If you do view source of the page, still i see the same XML without &gt; and &lt;

I wish to do this with my input XML specified above.

Comment: So, what is wrong with your current solution? Please, edit the question and explain.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are saying is when you view the resultant output in a browser, you see something like this...

```
<weatherdata> 
   <weather entityid="32226" alert="" ....
</weatherdata>
```

But when you do a 'View Source', you see this

```
&lt;weatherdata&gt;
    &lt;weather entityid="32226" alert=""
&lt;/weatherdata&gt;
```

That is to say, it has been 'escaped' for display purposes. The issue is your **cp:abstract** tag contains a string of text, not a string of XML, and so because you are outputing XML, the XSLT processor will escape the text it so as not to potential affect the main XML document.

The solution is to do this is do use **disable-output-escaping** on the **xsl:value-of** element

```
<xslt:template match="cp:abstract"> 
   <xslt:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"  /> 
</xslt:template>
```

When this is done, the following text will be output, which just happens to be in XML format

```
<weatherdata> 
   <weather entityid="32226" alert="" ....
</weatherdata>
```

Alternatively, you could change the **method** attribute on the **xsl:output** statement to **text**, and that should have the same effect

```
<xslt:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text"/>
```